# Will SQL index work for the below scenario

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Table A  With column (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) having a PK clustered index on Col1, Col2, Col3. Will this index help a search on Col1,Col2,Col4?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and index usage is also vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: what exactly is "a search"? An equality condition (`=`) ?  A `LIKE` condition? A range condition (`>=` and `<=`)? A not equals conditioN (`<>`)?

Comment: You've described a table with one index, and that's a clustered index at that. With just that structure, you know that the index is going to have to be used *anyway* because the data is stored in the leaves of the clustered index and, if nothing else, it would have to use it to look up `Col4`.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if an index exists for (Col1, Col2, Col3), a query that searches for (Col1, Col2, Col4) should be able to seek the index on Col1 and Col2.  I would expect a database engine would then return all matching rows to another step that filters the resulting rows on Col4.

In practice, the actual implementation would depend on the database engine.  It may be the query skips using the index completely and scans the table if the cost of a table scan is much less than an index seek.  If the query optimizer knows that Col1 is very unique, the query optimizer may use Col1 as the only seek predicate, and use another step in the query plan to filter matching rows by Col2 and Col4.